# Is magic in The Magicians Turing complete?

Tags: lev-grossman, the-magicians

The spells in The Magicans are fairly tricky with large amounts of seemingly arbitrary effort required for the simplest pre-determined effects. However, there are a few instances where more advanced spell-work is evident.

The Magicians spoiler:

> When Alice and Penny construct a spell by breaking down and reassembling the grammar of existing spells.

The Magician King spoiler:

> Julia finds out that there are a set number (at least known to the safehouse community) of fundamental spells (much like there are a set number of api methods in most libraries), but that these can be chained together for more complex effects.

The Magician's Land spoiler:

> The existence of a spell that creates a new universe, and Quentin's ability to suss out the effects of certain parts of it.

Is there evidence in the books of the ability for a spell to have conditional logic and memory so that it would be possible to construct a spell with any arbitrary logic, such that it would be able to simulate a Turing machine's logic and function?

Comment: You are looking for Merlin's Ghostwheel, from the Merlin Cycle of Zelazny's *Amber* series. :)

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that, too, when reading the series. You do not need much logic as OISCs show. A single conditional move could be enough. Perhaps a magical force field that let somethings pass is enough, like the Brakebills perimeter shield. I think they had watcher spells that trigger if something happens.

Comment: Now the question is, could a Turing complete spell trigger any other spell? A computer cannot change the physical world directly, but a spell can. Can the spell create spells? Because then one could cast an *universal spell*. Similar an universal Turing machine, the universal spell can do the same as any other spell. It is the only spell you would ever need to cast, every other spell can be emulated by activating the universal spell with certain inputs

Answer (score 0):

***Warning: Opinion based answer ahead!***

Magic is a super-set of Turing Complete.  Anything and everything is possible with magic.  (Except maybe destroying magic?  Not sure if there is a Conservation of Magic rule in universe, but it would make sense)
A couple random thoughts come to mind along the same topic:

- Some lands, like Fillory, are made entirely of magic.  If any entire world isn't proof of Turing Complete, I'm not sure what is.
- Magical power is the equivalent of RAM.  Quentin would never have been able to bring Alice back, or create his own land without [Mayakovsky's](http://themagicians.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_Mayakovsky)
  coin.
- Stoppard uses Horomancy, which he notes is like magical programming (don't have the exact quote)
- Multiple times they hack ATMs, and Quentin magic-hacks his father's computer when trying to see if there is [anything special](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120910/62703) about him.